# Python get the index of search within data frame and not an array with type of index

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get the value of the index and not an array following a criteria:

```
quarterValue = 20
indexOf = df[df["Quarter"]==quarterValue].index
```

The returning value is:

> Int64Index([34], dtype='int64')

What I need is only:

`34`

Answer (score 1):

Select first value by indexing:

```
idx = indexOf[0]
```

If possible sometimes is returned empty index solution failed, need trick with `next` and `iter` for first value with possible add default if no match:

```
idx = next(iter(indexOf), 'no value')
```

Comment: pls check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63618741/pandas-increment-value-on-groupby-with-a-condition)